# Why does iron router 0.9.4 data run while !ready() then again after all other hooks?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I put some debugging in my router config, and I notice that my `data` callback runs before `this.ready()` returns `true`, then runs again, *after*, for example, `action`! This seems quite odd, because presumably I'll need data for rendering my template(s). Why doesn't `data` run before `action`?

```
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'layout',
  loadingTemplate: 'loading'
});

/*
 * logged to console when navigating to 'home' route:
 *
 * 1. onRun
 * 2. waitOn
 * 3. onBeforeAction: not ready
 * 4. data: not ready
 *
 * ... 2 second delay (see sleep in publication)
 *
 * 5. onBeforeAction: ready
 * 6. action
 * 7. onAfterAction
 * 8. data: ready
 *
 * and, if you click the link to navigate away:
 *
 * 8. onStop
 */

Router.map(function() {
  this.route('home', {
    path: '/',
    onRun: function() {           // runs once (not after hot reload)
      console.log('onRun');
    },
    waitOn: function() {          // runs once
      console.log('waitOn');
      return [Meteor.subscribe('people')];
    },
    data: function() {            // runs multiple times
      if (this.ready()) {
        console.log('data: ready');
      } else {
        console.log('data: not ready');
      }
      return {
        'people': People.find()
      };
    },
    onBeforeAction: function() {  // runs multiple times
      if (this.ready()) {
        console.log('onBeforeAction: ready');
      } else {
        console.log('onBeforeAction: not ready');
      }
      // Will also run reactively. In other words,
      // if we called this.data().people.count(), our
      // onBeforeAction function would re-run more times,
      // because the cursor returned from People.find()
      // is a reactive data source.
    },
    action: function() {          // runs once
      console.log('action');
      this.render();
      // Will also run reactively.
    },
    onAfterAction: function() {   // runs once
      console.log('onAfterAction');
      // Will also run reactively.
    },
    onStop: function() {          // runs once if you navigate away
      console.log('onStop');
    }
  });

  return this.route('otherRoute', {
    path: '/otherRoute',
    template: 'home'
  });
});

Router.onBeforeAction('loading');
```

Full source code: https://gitlab.com/meonkeys/meteor-iron-router-data-last

Answer (score 0):

For your data, try this because right now, you are always returning your data regardless of `this.ready()`

```
    data: function() {
       if (this.ready()) {
          console.log('data: ready');

          return { 'people': People.find() };

       } else {
          console.log('data: not ready');
       }
},
```

Comment: This doesn't change the callback firing order. `data` still executes after `action`.